# Android - Working example of how to disable weekends using Square's TimeSquare Calendar

Tags: android, datepicker, calendar, android-time-square

I'm hoping to get a an example from someone who worked with Square's TimeSquare date-picker calendar. I wish to disable all the weekend dates for the coming year. Anyone achieved this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code, [try `setDateSelectableFilter()`](https://github.com/square/android-times-square/blob/android-times-square-parent-1.7.2/library/src/main/java/com/squareup/timessquare/CalendarPickerView.java#L985-L987):

```
CalendarPickerView cpv=(CalendarPickerView)findViewById(R.id.whatever_you_called_it);

cpv.setDateSelectableFilter(new DateSelectableFilter() {
  @Override
  public boolean isDateSelectable(Date date) {
    int dow=date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    return (dow != Calendar.SATURDAY && dow != Calendar.SUNDAY);
  }
});
```

Comment: I seen that - but not 100% sure how to implement - I have written a method (javatime) - that returns all the "working days" for the next 3 months - but this calendar widget seems to want date ranges ... could you suggest a working solution - or start of one ..?

Comment: @RMcGuigan: Um, `DateSelectableFilter` has one method: `isDateSelectable(Date)`. It returns a `boolean`, presumably `true` if it is selectable, `false` otherwise. So, implement `isDateSelectable()` on your `DateSelectableFilter` implementation to return `true` for weekdays, `false` for weekends. Then, attach an instance of your `DateSelectableFilter` implementation to the `CalendarPickerView` via `setDateSelectableFilter()`. Whether or not the view uses date ranges is determined by the `SelectionMode`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, How to change the color of the disabled date?

Comment: @Rakesh: Sorry, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness and possibly save others some time. Here is the full, complete method body

```
public void init(final Calendar calendar) {
    maxDate = calendar.getTime();
    calendarView.setOnInvalidDateSelectedListener(null);

    calendarView.setDateSelectableFilter(new DateSelectableFilter() {

        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        @Override
        public boolean isDateSelectable(Date date) {
            boolean isSelectable=true;
            cal.setTime(date);
            int dayOfWeek=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

            if(dayOfWeek==Calendar.SATURDAY || dayOfWeek==Calendar.SUNDAY){
                isSelectable=false;
            }
            return isSelectable;
        }
    });
    calendarView.init(new Date(), maxDate).withSelectedDate(new Date());

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for making weekends off in android-times-square calenderview,
Just use this code before init.

```
calendar.setOnInvalidDateSelectedListener(null);
    calendar.setDateSelectableFilter(new DateSelectableFilter() {

        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        @Override
        public boolean isDateSelectable(Date date) {
            boolean isSelecteable=true;
            cal.setTime(date);
            int dayOfWeek=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);        

                             //disable if weekend
            if(dayOfWeek==Calendar.SATURDAY || dayOfWeek==Calendar.SUNDAY){
               isSelecteable=false; 
            }
            return isSelecteable;
        }
    });
```